# Bull Arab entertainment

Tags: dogs, socializing, pregnancy, large-dogs

We have a beautiful natured large bull Arab dog. Due to being pregnant I have been told to reduce my interactions with him incase my tummy gets a knock to it.

My neighbour is walking him some mornings for me but I just feel like it’s not fair on him that that’s the only entertainment he gets each day if any.

I have never had a dog before. This is my partners dog whom I have now moved in with. So I’m just learning.

Can anyone please tell me ways to keep this beautiful dog entertained and feeling loved? For the past year or two I have thrown a balls for him and chased him all around the yard and washed him and smothered him in affection. But now I’m increasingly finding it difficult to do so due to my size and energy levels.

It’s not fair on him. Someone please give me some ideas? Thankyou in advance :)

Comment: @AllisonC this dog is pregnant and this needs to be addressed specifically, which the other question does not.

Comment: @YvetteHorsewoman Is the dog pregnant? My reading of the question is that the asker is the one who is pregnant and the dog is male (and therefore can't be pregnant), in which case the other question does address it.

Comment: @AllisonC oh yes, you're right the owner is pregnant. Hm I'll go over the dupe target again and check

Comment: Thankyou for your assistance. I am pregnant, not the dog :) I will definitely give these ideas a try!! Just worried because he’s so goofy and big and heavy that my belly may get injured. I feel so sorry for every animal I see at the moment as I feel like they are all sad but I think it’s just hormones. Thanks again :)